# Can't update Jcombobox in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have the below code(summarized) in which I am trying to update the model for my combobox from another class. Based on my prints I have made, it seems the model gets updated, but the UI keeps showing the same value, it doesnt get the new values.

I have tried repaint() method, but it still does not work.
Any help?

```
public class MainGUI  {

   public JComboBox cmbDatagroupName= new JComboBox();
   public DefaultComboBoxModel modelDataGroup = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

 public void initialize(){

    cmbDatagroupName.setMaximumRowCount(100);
    cmbDatagroupName.setBounds(173, 15, 319, 25);
    modelDataGroup.addElement("Hello");
    cmbDatagroupName.setModel(modelDataGroup);


}

public void testing(DefaultComboBoxModel model){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Im the method testing. Items "+cmbDatagroupName.getItemCount()); //This prints 1 element
    cmbDatagroupName.setModel(model);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Updated model. Items "+cmbDatagroupName.getItemCount()); //This prints 6 elements, coming from other class

    }

}
```

I have my other class as below, where I call the method testing() in the click of a button, and I send the new model.

```
public class LoginFrm{
JButton okButton = new JButton("Connect");
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    DefaultComboBoxModel modelDataGroup = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
                        modelDataGroup.addElement("1");
                        modelDataGroup.addElement("2");
                        modelDataGroup.addElement("3");
                        modelDataGroup.addElement("4");
                        modelDataGroup.addElement("5");
                        modelDataGroup.addElement("6");
                        new MainGUI().testing(modelDataGroup);
                        dispose();
}

}
```

Like I mentioned, the model in MainGUI, gets the right amount of items, and if I do a print of values in memory, I can see them, is just the swing UI wont show the new model items..
Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Why are you creating a new MainGui each time you click the button?

Comment: @FredK I guess with all the attempts I was doing I didnt notice, I have changed that properly to just call the object from MainGUI, but still wont work... everything gets updated in memory, but just the Jcombo is not getting "repainted"

Comment: @SargeOrona `ActionListener` has a `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method that much written

Comment: If you still need help, then you will want to improve this question by creating and posting your [mcve].

Comment: @Abdul are you talking about my button action in the other class?